# How to select winner of condorcet election via matrix?

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, max, rank, pairwise

I would like to understand how the condorcet winner is elected in a ranked-choice election.

There is an example on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_method) - under the sub-heading "Pairwise counting and matrices" under the heading "Basic procedure", in which the pairwise comparison matrix is constructed for candidates A, B, C, and D in an election. The matrix looks like:

From this matrix, it is concluded that A is the condorcet winner. I can see that the result is correct, but do not understand how to algorithmically approach this problem.

`

```
[[0, 2, 2, 2],

[1, 0, 1, 2],

[1, 2, 0, 2],

[1, 1, 1, 0]]
```

`

A more complicated example can be found on table 2-a at [accuratedemocracy](https://www.accuratedemocracy.com/c_tally.htm); when considering a different election with candidates A, B, C, and D; they find that C is the winner, but one can click cells C and D to verify that they earn the same number of votes in the pairwise comparison matrix. Why is C the winner and not D?

Suppose one has constructed the pair-wise comparison matrix. How can one select the condorcet winner from this matrix?

An example, one can construct the pairwise comparison matrix in python using the following code:

`

```
import numpy as np

unranked_choices = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

def generate_preference_matrix(ranked_choices):
    num_candidates = len(ranked_choices)
    preference_matrix = np.zeros((num_candidates, num_candidates))

    for i, candidate_i in enumerate(unranked_choices):
        for j, candidate_j in enumerate(unranked_choices):
            if i != j:
                if ranked_choices.index(candidate_i) < ranked_choices.index(candidate_j):
                    preference_matrix[i, j] += 1  # Candidate_i is preferred over candidate_j
                # else:
                #     preference_matrix[i, j] = 0  # No preference or candidate_j is preferred over candidate_i

    return preference_matrix


# Test with example ranked choices
ranked_choices = ['B', 'C', 'A', 'D']  # Ranked choices in order of preference
preference_matrix = generate_preference_matrix(ranked_choices)
print(preference_matrix)

ranked_choices = ['A', 'D', 'B', 'C']  # Ranked choices in order of preference
preference_matrix = generate_preference_matrix(ranked_choices)
print(preference_matrix)
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sum the preference matrices in order to calculate the ranking. The candidate with the highest total is the declared the winner.

```py
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations


def get_ranked_order(candidates, preferences):

    def get_preference_matrix(preference_order):
        nonlocal candidates
        matrix = np.zeros((len(preference_order), len(preference_order)))
        for a, b in combinations(candidates, 2):
            # Head to Head ranking comparisons
            if preference_order.index(a) < preference_order.index(b):
                matrix[candidates.index(a), candidates.index(b)] += 1
            if preference_order.index(b) < preference_order.index(a):
                matrix[candidates.index(b), candidates.index(a)] += 1
        return matrix

    # Sum the preference matrices
    sum_matrix = np.zeros((len(candidates), len(candidates)))
    for p in preferences:
        sum_matrix = np.add(sum_matrix, get_preference_matrix(p))

    # Sort candidates by decreasing scores
    return sorted(zip(candidates, [sum(r) for r in sum_matrix]),
                  key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)
```

Using the data from the example on the Wikipedia page:

```py
vote_candidates = ("A", "B", "C", "D")
voter_preferences = [
    ("B", "C", "A", "D"), 
    ("A", "D", "B", "C"), 
    ("A", "C", "B", "D")
]

rankings = get_ranked_order(vote_candidates, voter_preferences)

if rankings[0][1] > rankings[1][1]:
    print(f"Condorcet Winner is {rankings[0]}")
else:
    print(rankings)
```

Result:

```
Condorcet Winner is ('A', 7.0)
```

Comment: I see, the maximum row-wise sum of the matrix corresponds to the condorcet winner - thank you. The method works great, but there is a small typo from the example - the `voter_preferences=["D", "A", "C", "B"]`, which makes the output `("A", 6.0)` (though A is still the winner).